# Flutter Objectbox: how to store a Map attribute?

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I have a class with a Map attribute, but it seems it doesn't store this attribute. All other attributes are well stored:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
@Entity()
class PossessionStats {
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: 0)
  int id;
  String cardUuid;
  int total;
  Map<String, int>? totalByVersion;

  CardPossessionStats({
    this.id = 0,
    required this.cardUuid,
    this.total = 0,
    this.totalByVersion,
  });
}
```

When I save one:

```dart
stats = PossessionStats(cardUuid: card.uuid);
if (stats.totalByVersion == null) {
  stats.totalByVersion = Map();
}
stats.totalByVersion!
    .update(version, (value) => quantity, ifAbsent: () => quantity);
stats.total = stats.totalByVersion!.values
    .fold(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element);
box.put(stats);
```

When I get the results (after a refresh), I can see `total` is correct but `totalByVersion` is still empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For an unsupported type, you'll need to add a "converter", as described by the [docs (Custom types)](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types). You can adapt the docs to your code, for example using `json` as the storage format:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
@Entity()
class PossessionStats {
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: 0)
  int id;
  String cardUuid;
  int total;
  Map<String, int>? totalByVersion;

  String? get dbTotalByVersion =>
      totalByVersion == null ? null : json.encode(totalByVersion);

  set dbTotalByVersion(String? value) {
    if (value == null) {
      totalByVersion = null;
    } else {
      totalByVersion = Map.from(
          json.decode(value).map((k, v) => MapEntry(k as String, v as int)));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It doesn't work at my first try, but with your example it's fine.

Comment: Here is the import
`import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';`